# Add Original Custom View to the Window

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiview

I added my custom view to the window but it doesn't work. I tried to figure it out but it doesn't work well. (I created this project with the empty project template without using storyboards). This screen is supposed to show the red rectangle towards the bottom right corner of the screen.

**I wanted to add my custom view showing red screen to the window, but it just shows the white screen.**

AppDelegate.m:

```
//
//  HypnosisterAppDelegate.m
//  Hypnosister
//
//  Created by TSH on 12/1/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 TSH. All rights reserved.
//

#import "HypnosisterAppDelegate.h"
#import "HypnosisterViewController.h"
#import "HypnosisView.h"

@implementation HypnosisterAppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    HypnosisterViewController *test = [[HypnosisterViewController alloc]     initWithNibName:@"HypnosisterViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]  initWithRootViewController:test];
    self.window.rootViewController = nav;

    CGRect viewFrame = CGRectMake(16, 24, 10, 15);

    HypnosisView *view = [[HypnosisView alloc] initWithFrame:viewFrame];
    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [[self window] addSubview:view];

    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

@end
```

---

[edit]

I just messed up the ordering.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    HypnosisterViewController *test = [[HypnosisterViewController alloc]     initWithNibName:@"HypnosisterViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]  initWithRootViewController:test];
    self.window.rootViewController = nav;

    CGRect viewFrame = CGRectMake(160, 240, 100, 150);

    HypnosisView *view = [[HypnosisView alloc] initWithFrame:viewFrame];
    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [[self window] addSubview:view];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Please, do not include your solution in the question: you should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@toshi You code is correct just you missed the ordering .Use this code it will work.Let me know if it doesn't work.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    HypnosisterViewController *test = [[HypnosisterViewController alloc]     initWithNibName:@"HypnosisterViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]  initWithRootViewController:test];
    self.window.rootViewController = nav;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];


    CGRect viewFrame = CGRectMake(16, self.window.frame.size.height - 24, 10, 15);

    HypnosisView *view = [[HypnosisView alloc] initWithFrame:viewFrame];
    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [[self window] addSubview:view];

    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: @Toshi : Try it let me know.

Comment: I wish I could vote this up but not enough reputation xd Thanks anyways!

Comment: :sorry again! It might be a weird question but What does this code "self.window.frame.size.height -" work? and how come I needed to put it?

Comment: self.window.frame.size.height it gives you the height of UIWindow and if you subract the height of your view then it places it on bottom.you can understand by watching http://i.stack.imgur.com/lB6tf.png

Comment: Thanks! I got it ,but I'm still not sure why it doesn't work if I don't add "self.window.frame.size.height", because I thought I used CGRect for setting on the view and it's not related to window. And the book doesn't explain it at all. It's weird but I guess I made the empty project from scratch and might add something for the new version of Xcode?

Answer (score 1):

As you set navigationcontroller as rootviewcontroller so HypnosisterViewController will appear every time no doubts. If you want to add a custom view to have to add as a subview on the HypnosisterViewController.

```
 HypnosisView *view = [[HypnosisView alloc] initWithFrame:viewFrame];
[view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[test.view addSubview:view];
```

Hopefully it will work

Comment: Thanks alot!! It works:) I just wonder how  navigationcontroller and rootviewcontroller work together? I'm pretty new here and if you don't mind, could you explain it little bit?

Comment: If you work with an empty project , it requires a rootViewController to start. Then you have to use navigation controller or tab bar controller according to the requirement of the project. The way you coded is the proper way to set a navigation controller as a rootviewcontroller.

Comment: Okay, now I understand it,so Can I add view objects to "window" and to "view" in Viewcontroller?  I know viewcontroller has a view property.

Comment: IF you set a view controller as a rootviewcontroller then you have to add a custom view as a subview on view controller

Answer (score 0):

There is two points

1- The coordinate of the view in iOS begin from top-left so this frame (16, 24, 10, 15) will in the top-left of the view as frame calculated as (x,y,width,height)

2- Window does not responds to device Orientation. It will be always Portrait. If you rotate your device you will need to re-calculate the view Coordinate.

Comment: Thanks,and that's right! It's supposed to be the top-left on the view, but if you don't mine , could you please give me some clue to show the view on the screen? cause there is nothing except white screen.

Comment: Thank you:) I've gotta keep it up!